# What does it mean to divide by the standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, image-processing

I'm trying to "variance-normalize" an image. In order to do so, I subtract the mean from the pixel value (to have a $0$ mean), and divide by the standard deviation (to have a unit variance) right? But I've also seen division by the standard deviation, since it's obviously not the same, what does it do?

I'm also a bit confused about the values I get after normalization: some values still more than $1.0$ or less than $-1.0$. I thought a unit variance means a variance from $-1.0$ to $1.0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you divide all the values by the standard deviation, then you will then have a distribution with a standard deviation equal to $1$ (and so a variance equal to $1^2 = 1$). The difference is that the mean is not $0$, unless it was originally.

You seem to be confusing the variance with (half) the range.  The [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28statistics%29) is the difference between the minimum possible value and the maximum possible value.  The [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) is the expected value of the square of the differences between the actual values and the mean of the distribution, and the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is the square root of the variance.

Except in a special case, the range will be more than twice the standard deviation: the special case is where the distribution only takes two values, and takes those with equal probability. So if you have a standardized distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$ then you will usually find some values outside the interval $[-1,1]$: for a standard normal distribution, there is a probability over 31% that a value will be outside that interval.